How to Import Existing IAC-Generated Resources into CDK with TypeScript Without Using the Template Path?
We have a template generated from an IAC generator that we migrated to TypeScript. We want to import it into CDK while keeping the existing resources, not through the template path. How can we achieve this?
I tried using from*attribute to reference it, expecting it to recognize that the resource already exists, but I encountered an error.
